# Best way to control multiple stepper motors (6 of them)

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller

I have a small K-cup filling/sealing machine mechanically complete, now I need to control it.

I have installed (1) nema 23 stepper motor to rotate an attached disk that has a hole for 4 empty k-cups, 90 degrees apart.

I have installed (1) nema 17 stepper motor to dispense an empty K-cup.

I have installed (1) nema 17 stepper motor to rotate an auger within coffee ground filled hopper, to fill the empty K-cup.

I have installed (1) nema 17 stepper motor to place a lid over filled k-cup.

I have installed (1) nema 17 stepper motor to actuate a heat seal head.

I have installed (1) nema 17 stepper motor to remove filled/sealed k-cup when rotary disk is in "stop" mode at 45 degree position, assuming the lid seal position is "zero position"'

Next event, rotary disk steps 45 more degrees where an empty K-cup is inserted. 45 degrees + 45 degrees = 90.

Simultaneously,(same time frame), while a new empty k-cup is being inserted at 90 degrees, a cup is being filled at 180 degrees,& a lid is being placed at on cup at 270 degrees, & a lid is being heat sealed at 360 degrees, zero position, a new cycle begins now with nema 23 stepping 45 degrees where sealed cup is removed, etc,etc.

Is this an application for a standard, off the self HMI/PLC, like a Unitronic's V-350 or similar?

All the steppers have 2mm lead screw pitch and it seems quite simple to determine how many pulses forward/backward each motor would require to perform required functions. I don't think I need to micro step, 1.8 degree steps should be close enough.

Where do I start? Any recommendations, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me like you're after a 6 axis stepper controller and 6x stepper driver. A quick google gives a lot of options, and as you say the standard PLCs can do it. What more help do you need? (remembering we don't do product recomendations on this site)

Comment: Thank You Puffafish, I will pursue your suggestion.

Comment: Depending on your budget, these types of motors exist with a built-in positional encoder, controller and Ethernet port.  Supply DC power, and an Ethernet cable, plug them all into a generic Ethernet switch, and away you go!  We've done this, and with some straight-forward Python, it was quick and easy.   Good Luck!

Comment: what advice are you looking for, apart from take what you need to drive 1 motor and multiply it by 6 (except the CPU). If you're looking for a recommendation for a specific system to buy, that's not allowed on this website because the answers get outdated quickly.

Comment: Thank all of you for your suggestions, I will pursue them.